# get JSON value for URL and send to another intent

Tags: android, json, android-json

i am trying to fetch the json value for api. What my api is showing json as below

```
{
    "resultCode": 0,
    "resultMessage": "Login Success",
    "data": {
        "userid": "2",
        "username": "abc",
        "email": "mrabc@abc.com",
        "access_token": "Bw3jvwGHb4Iq4"
    }
}
```

how can i get the value of data??

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: Have you checked all answers?

Comment: thank you guyz,.. u save my day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This...

```
String result = "your json string";

try {

    /* converting String to Json Object.. */
    JSONObject json_result = new JSONObject(result); 

    /* getting object values */
    String  resultCode = json_result.getJSONObject("resultCode"); 
    String  resultMessage= json_result.getJSONObject("resultMessage");

    /* creating new Object  for data */
    JSONObject json_data = jsondata.getJSONObject("data"); 

    /*fetching values from data */
    String  userid= json_data .getJSONObject("userid"); 
    String  username= json_data .getJSONObject("username");
    String  email= json_data .getJSONObject("email");
    String  access_token= json_data .getJSONObject("access_token");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Note :** 
Always Use Try-Catch block For converting JSON Values to string..it helps you to handle `Exception` and stops your application from crashing...

Answer (score 2):

First convert your json response from server to a string then try like this:

```
JSONObject rootObject= new JSONObject(strFromServer);
JSONObject dataObject= rootObject.getJSONObject("data");
String userID = dataObject.getString("userid");
String username= dataObject.getString("username");
and so on.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject (str);

 String resultCode = jobj .getString("resultCode");
 String resultMessage = jobj .getString("resultMessage");
 JSONObject jo = jobj.getJSONObject(data);

 String userId= jo .getString("userid");
 String userName= jo .getString("username");
 String email= jo .getString("email");
```

Comment: there is no array in OP JSON "Data" is JSON object

Answer (score 0):

Every `{}` represents a JSON Object.

Hence you first get the JSONObject from the String  : `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);`

Now, data contains another JSON Object since the contents are enclosed in `{}`. So, `JSONObject dataObject = obj.getJSONObject("data");`

Now, to get String values from the dataObject,

```
dataObject.getString("userId");
dataObject.getString("username"); 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
 JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject (str);

 String resultCode = jobj.getString("resultCode");
 String resultMessage = jobj .getString("resultMessage");
 JSONObject jobj1 = jobj.getJSONObject("data");

 String userid= jobj1.getString("userid");
 String username= jobj1.getString("username");
 String email= jobj1.getString("email");
```